# Canceling a child activity in an Activity group when changing tabs

Tags: android, android-intent, tabactivity, activitygroup

(I know that Activity Groups and Tabs have been deprecated.  I cannot redesign my app at the moment, so I want to finish it with the current design if possible.)

I have a TabActivity with three tabs, A, B, and C.  Tab C is an ActivityGroup with two child activities, C1 and C2.  C2 is always called from C1 and dismissed by setting the C1 View and restarting the C1 intent.  All this works fine.  My problem is that if the user selects the A or B tab while in the C2 activity, I want the C2 activity to cancel.  The next time that the C Tab is selected, the C1 activity should display.  Same thing if the user exits the application and re-enters it.

I have implemented the OnTabChangeListener(), so I know when a new tab is selected, and I can even tell if the C2 tab is active (or was before the tab changed).  My question is how to cancel the C2 activity so that when the C tab is selected, the default C1 activity is started instead of returning to the previously active C2 tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can make use of your onPause() in Tab C and override it with the same code what you could have used of getting back from c2 to c1. Since `onPause()` will be called only when you come out of that particular tab, your activity group will be restored at the background, and when you get back to that Tab C you can see your C1 at the first place.

Comment: I thought of this, but the way I exit to c2 to c1 is to restart the C1 intent and setContentView() with the c1 view.  This would cause problems switching to the new Tab activity (A or B)

Comment: Give it a try.. I dont think it would cause you any problem unless you are using network too much in that activity

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use broadcast sender and receiver for that purpose. In onpause create a broadcast receiver. I am suggesting this because if you want to finish c2 from any other place also then you can do it easily by sending broadcast. Use this code :

```
BroadcastReceiver broadcast_receiver = null; // DECLARE IT IN YOUR CLASS.

// WRITE BELOW CODE IN onPause OF C2 ACTIVITY.
broadcast_receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("finish_c2")) {
            unregisterReceiver(broadcast_receiver);
            finish();
        }
    }
};
    registerReceiver(broadcast_receiver, new IntentFilter("finish_c2"));
```

To finish your activity just send broadcast from any place.

```
//WRITE THE BELOW CODE WHERE YOU WANT TO FINISH C2 ACTIVITY.
Intent intent = new Intent("finish_c2");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

hope it will help you ask if any problem occurs.

Comment: This might work, but it seems like an odd way to go about it.  How would I call finish on a child activity from the Activity Group onPause()?

Comment: you are not calling finish in child activity. You are calling finish in C2 activity only which you want to finish. You are sending broadcast from child activity only. Don't worry this code I have tested several times in my module and it is working fine. Example is A->B->C like A start B and B Start C now you want to remove B from C. If you can able to finish activity B then A will me automatically just below to C because its a Stack and if your remove B then C automatically shift down.

Comment: There are other ways also to do that. One is do not finish activity B. Set a flag in your activity C and then Recieve your flag in onActivityResult of activity B if flag is true then finish activity B. In this way activity B will be there but finish of actvity will be so rapid that no one can able to know whether there was any activity B present or not... so different ways choose suitable..

Comment: ya anytime :) but notify me is it working for your case or not.

Comment: I did not actually try this, because Andro's solution worked, and I had been leaning that way anyway.  Thanks for the input, I suspect it probably would have worked also.